# Not able to automate apply button in naukri

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I was trying to automate the apply button in naukri. I have tried both id attribute and xpath by text function which is only present in the Elements.

driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//button[text()='Apply'])[1]")).click();

Comment: Add the `HTML` source for Apply button and what `error` are you getting ?

Comment: (//button[@id='apply-button'])[1]
NoSuchElementException

Comment: This is not `HTML` of the element, you have pasted `xpath` Please provide the complete detail